# How do I find the range of a transition matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am unsure as to how to find the range of a transition matrix.
For example,
suppose $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1& 1 & -1\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ for a linear transform $T:V\to V$

Being that the kernel is a subspace of the range, I caclulated it, $\ker(T)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$. However, I'm not sure if this will help me. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by range, other than asking whether or not the given matrix spans any vector in 3D ?

Comment: please define the *range*

Comment: Why is $\ker(T) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$?  If $T \, : \, \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, then $\ker(T) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, and since $A$ is a transition (change-of-basis) matrix, $\ker(T) = \{(0,0,0)\}$.  But as others have mentioned, what is the *range*?  The kernel of $T\, : \, V \to W$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: Earth to Oscar, come in please. Anything to say about the comments and the answer?

Answer (score 0):

First, convince yourself that the range is the same as the column space of $A$.

You have probably learned how to find a basis for the column space of a matrix.